# Computer acts like it has lost internet, but is still connected

Tags: windows, internet, anti-virus

I am having a weird problem with my laptop. My computer will act like it has lost connection to the internet (Slack cant send messages, Chrome says no internet access, stuff like that), but current applications that are currently using the internet keep working (I can have twitch streaming hours after the problem occurs). Once it happens, My computer remains that way until I restart my computer. It happens at random times, and I cant find a pattern as to what I am doing that could cause it. In fact, I am posting this right now while my computer says there is no internet connection!

I have an Alienware R17 running windows 10. I also have the basic windows security running, no other antivirus (I have heard it might be an antivirus problem)

Comment: Run TCP/IP Reset as follows:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer and test

Comment: @John Smidt I am wondering if John's answer helped. Please post back and let us know if John's comment helped with your question. It may help alot of others as well.

Comment: It could be DNS. Try opening a command window and running `ping 8.8.8.8` then, if that works, try `ping google.com`

Comment: Thanks everyone. The problem happens about once every 2 days. I've tried out John's answer, and ill update if the problem happens again, or if it doesn't show up for a bit.

Comment: Ok, I just had it happen again, doing what John said did not help with the problem. Restarting always fixes it, but it goes out a few days later.